# C++20 string literal template argument working example

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Could someone post a minimal reproducible example of C++20's feature string template as template argument?

this one from [ModernCpp](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-the-core-language) does not compile:

```
template<std::basic_fixed_string T>
class Foo {
    static constexpr char const* Name = T;
public:
    void hello() const;
};

int main() {
    Foo<"Hello!"> foo;
    foo.hello();
}
```

I've managed to write a working solution based on [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/bhxx49/c20_string_literals_as_nontype_template/):

```
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned N>
struct FixedString 
{
    char buf[N + 1]{};
    constexpr FixedString(char const* s) 
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i != N; ++i) buf[i] = s[i];
    }
    constexpr operator char const*() const { return buf; }

    // not mandatory anymore
    auto operator<=>(const FixedString&) const = default;
};
template<unsigned N> FixedString(char const (&)[N]) -> FixedString<N - 1>;

template<FixedString Name>
class Foo 
{
public:
    auto hello() const { return Name; }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo<"Hello!"> foo;
    std::cout << foo.hello() << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4kwfnP)

but does provide a custom implementation for a fixed string. So what should be the state-of-the-art implementation by now?

Comment: Note that C++20 NTTPs have changed over the course of standardization. Strong structural equality no longer uses a defaulted `operator<=>` even though it did at the time of the reddit post. (More accurately, the new terminology is "structural type".)

Comment: Do implementations support user-defined NTTPs yet? If so, which ones, and how good is that support?

Comment: My opinion is that your implementation looks like state of the art! template-id placeholder for the non type template parameter, defaulted three way comparison operator that implies the equality operator, structural type, and no more that what is necessary! Could the implementation be more concise?

Answer (score 6):

[P0259 `fixed_string`](http://wg21.link/P0259) has been [retired](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/396#issuecomment-509685595) on the basis that most of its use cases are better achieved via [P0784 More constexpr containers](http://wg21.link/P0784) (aka constexpr destructors and transient allocation) - i.e. being able to use `std::string` itself within constexpr context.

Of course, even if you can use `std::string` in constexpr, that doesn't make it usable as an NTTP, but it doesn't look like we're going to get a structural string class into the Standard any time soon. I would recommend using your own structural string class for now, being ready to alias it to an appropriate third-party class should one emerge in a popular library, or to a standard one if and when that happens.

Comment: Is just me or it is weird to provide a new functionality but not a standard container to do that?

Comment: @Moia structural NTTPs aren't just for using strings as template parameters - they're a more general facility. If the two features had been tied together we might not have got either.